# Where to find **options in python official docs?

Tags: python

Sometimes when searching python official docs about functions. It has something like this.

The question is where to find those mysterious ****options**?

Yes, I can find them in some tutorial articles. But why not just list them directly in the official doc.

[image]

Comment: [Very related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320739/where-to-find-documentation-of-kwargs-args-of-functions/63320803#63320803) question.

Comment: Note though for this case specifically, it does list them above that under the "Native Load/Save Dialogs" header.

Comment: Never thought it in this way :-(

It is best you inspect the source code or search online !!

Comment: The thing with `**kwargs` is that they are dynamic, and therefore it is impossible for any documentation generation tool to know what options are supported.  It's up to whoever wrote the library to explicitly document those options.

Comment: The `tkinter` module *doesn't know* what the allowed options are - `**options` is the actual parameter list that those functions are defined with.  It just passes on whatever options were provided to the underlying Tck/Tk implementation, which will produce an error if any of them aren't actually implemented there.  Any further details about the options come from a docstring that someone typed in, rather than anything explicitly given in the code.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation.